# How to force Android always start from Launcher activity

Tags: android

In my app I have a startup `Activity` which shows my logo and does a few web requests, after which it starts the main `Activity` and finishes itself. 
The problem is that I always need Android to start my app from startup `Activity` and do the requests. But when user presses home `Button` on main `Activity` and app goes to the background it is being recycled by Android after some time. And when user presses the icon of my app again Android stars from main activity not from startup `Activity`.
So I need that any time Android recycles my main `Activity` it starts my app from startup activity but not from main `Activity`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Activity Life Cycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

First of all , Our data nothing will be changed while app goes into `onPause()` state.then why you need to call the request's again ?

if it's rigid `finish()` the app in MainActivity `onPause()` or  you can call the requests from MainActivity itself.use `onResume()` so that you can get the app resume state.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a StartActivity, that checks the application state and then redirects to the correct Activity and then destroys itself.

For example (redirecting to the login screen when not logged in yet):

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (MyState.getInstance().isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I use my Startup Activity for this reason. But when the user is logged in I need to make some web requests and update some data in my preferences and only after that I can start my Main Activity because Main activity depends on that data. But When Android starts directly Main Activity this data can be out of date.

Comment: After loading, you can pass the data using a Bundle in your Intent. And then use onSaveInstanceState() and onCreate(Bundle) to save/restore your Actvity state.  It will be as if the Activity was never destroyed...

Comment: If your data can get out of data, you might want to load the data in your MainActivity instead and show the user that it's refreshing or something.